# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-bootstrap-validation'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-bootstrap

### Issue

I keep getting the following error in webpack

```
Error: Cannot find module 'react-bootstrap-validtion'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Have I referenced or installed the module incorrectly?

This is how I've done it following the example in the official website. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-validation)

---

### Environment

This are the node environment I'm working with

```
npm -v
3.10.7

nvm version
v5.11.1

node -v
v5.11.1
```

---

This is how I've installed the module

`npm install --save react-bootstrap-validation`

---

### React Component

This is how I've implemented my React component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { ButtonInput } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Form } from 'react-bootstrap-validation'

export default class LoginForm extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      showModal: false,
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  }

  _handleValidSubmit(values) {}
  _handleInvalidSubmit(errors, values) {}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="account">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="page-title">Login</div>
            <div className="page-desc">Email used at sign up</div>
            <Form
              onValidSubmit={this._handleValidSubmit.bind(this)}
              onInvalidSubmit={this._handleInvalidSubmit.bind(this)}>
              <ValidatedInput
                type="text"
                label="Email"
                name="email"
                validate="required,isEmail"
                errorHelp={{
                  required: "Please enter your e-mail",
                  isEmail: "Email is invalid"
                }}
              />

              <ValidatedInput
                type="password"
                label="Password"
                name="password"
                validate="required,isLength:6:60"
                errorHelp={{
                  required: "Please specify a password",
                  isEmail: "Password must be at least 6 characters"
                }}
              />

              <ButtonInput
                type="submit"
                bsSize="large"
                bsStyle="primary"
                value="LOGIN"
              />
            </Form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: `validtion` isn't the same as `validation`.

Comment: @AndrewL. thank you!
That was fixed. Please ignore it.

I'm still getting the following errors:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-bootstrap-validation' in '/usr/src/app/app/js/components/main'`

Comment: That conflicts with the error given in the question

Comment: can you see the package folder `react-bootstrap-validation` in your node_modules folder?

Comment: @Hardy thank you for your comments! Yes. I've attached the output of 'npm list' below! Please refer to it if needed!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Module not found error occurs when you are using some module and that module is not installed or node is unable to locate that module due to wrong path.

> One module you are trying to install have either dependency on other
> modules as well

so sometime not all the modules are installed correctly due to some permission security issues.

So please try with giving all permission or **run as Root and add sudo if you are using ubuntu machine.**

So you can install that module via directly running the following command:-

```
npm install react-bootstrap-validation --save
```

or if you are using linux/ubuntu than run following command:-

```
sudo npm install react-bootstrap-validation --save
```

Or first please check in the console when installing the module that

> is there any dependency error showing in the console

if so then please also attach that console, on that case you need to install dependent module also as separately via npm install.

Hope this will help!

Thanks

Comment: the above `npm install react-bootstrap-validtion --save` 
SHOULD BE `npm install react-bootstrap-validation --save`
NB: spelling of "validation".

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use this:

```
npm i --save react-bootstrap
```

Answer (score 0):

If the accepted answer doesn't work for you, it could be that your version of `bootstrap-react` is newer than the version of whatever you're trying to implement/emulate.

For me, I checked the `package.json` file of the tutorial I was looking at and found:

```
"react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2",
```

You can also just run `npm list` in the project if you have it downloaded on your machine.

But when I ran `npm list` on my own project I got

```
react-bootstrap@2.0.0
```

So I ran

```
npm install react-bootstrap@1.5.2
```

and resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This sorted my issue

npm install --save react-bootstrap-validation

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal in your project's root directory (where your package.json file is located) and run the following commands:

with NPM

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

ONLY If you use TypeScript

```
npm install --save-dev @types/react-bootstrap @types/bootstrap
```

And you should import bootstrap in `index.css` or `app.css`

```
@import '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```